# Has LT Spice recently changed the current load simulation?

Tags: ltspice

To answer a question here, I started an older simulation an got unexpected results...

So here is a minimal simulation to demonstrate my issue:

It seems a neg. Voltage over a current load source does not result in zero current but neg. current:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anybody replicate / verify this issue?

---

http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=I_Current_Source

states the behaviour I am used to:

> If the source is flagged as a load, the source is forced to be dissipative, that is, the current goes to zero if the voltage between nodes n+ and n- goes to zero or a negative value.

---

**Update: Analog Devices answered my question if this is a bug**

> ...to clarify that, the load current indicating zero while the supply is negative, was considered as an bug in the model previously. As the current will alternates and changes the direction of current flow this is indicated in the flow of current will change the direction as well. If you plot the power you can see that the power supplied is equal to power consumed at the load.

Comment: That explanation from them is plain wrong: the output is meant to model a *current *load**, that does not continue if the voltage drops below zero, not a *power*. If the voltage drops then the current would be *generated* by the load. And of course the powers are equal, you only have a source and a load and the wires are only visual, it would violate the whole Universe otherwise. It was buggy in IV because it wouldn't limit the current, it would mimic the voltage across, multiplied by its value, but here it's also buggy: it works well on the positive voltages, but not the other way. A pity.

Comment: I am not happy with it eigher... breaking old simulations is a no Go. If their opinion is that there is a need for the new behaviour, why not add just a new component to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour was introduced in LTspice XVII, since I can verify the exact same output in the `Oct 7 2016` release, which is the first one to come after the initial "demo". LTspice IV is not affected. You can write to the developers at the address in the `Help > About` menu. It will help if you'll be short and to the point (attach this example, too).

Comment: Thx, just mailed analog devices as suggested

Comment: Interesting. I'll be interested in the responses should the OP be able to add them at some point.

Comment: @jonk It's appended at the end of the OP. The comment below it shows my thinking on this: I think they're both wrong, but that's just me.